# How to show specific value when click on any radio button in console using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

I am having difficulty to show a value of selected radio button. When I click on question 1 then result 1 should be display on console but I am getting all the values of radio button.Can anyone help me please? Thanks

html

```
<form onsubmit="return answers(event)">
    <label>Question 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="1">
    <label>Question 2</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="2">
    <label>Question 3</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="3">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>

    function answers(event)
    {
        var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
        [...q].forEach(question =>{

            console.log(question.value);
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Not related to your issue: to group radio buttons you need to set the `name` property. To get the selected one you need to check the property`checked` like `question.checked` or use the selector `.question:checked`. [radio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check to see if it is checked with `question.checked`.

```
function answers(event)
    {
        var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question');
        [...q].forEach(question =>{
            if(question.checked){
                console.log(question.value);
            }
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

You might also want to add names to all the radios, because the idea of radios is that only one of them can be ticked at a time. `name` does that for you:

```
<form onsubmit="return answers(event)">
    <label>Question 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="1" name="question">
    <label>Question 2</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="2" name="question">
    <label>Question 3</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="3" name="question">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: lastly, how to validate if question is not checked?

Comment: `if(question.checked){ console.log(question.value);} else //not checked`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking the `checked` property inside a loop. You could use the [:checked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:checked) pseudo-class to only select checked radios.

```js
function answers(event)
{
    var q = document.querySelectorAll('.question:checked');
    [...q].forEach(question =>{

        console.log(question.value);
    });

    event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return answers(event)">
    <label>Question 1</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="1" name="question">
    <label>Question 2</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="2" name="question">
    <label>Question 3</label>
    <input type="radio" class="question" value="3" name="question">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Also be aware to use the [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) property to group radio buttons.